# how to fix No Instance(s) Available in wmic?

Tags: windows, wmi, wmic

When I put the command wmic qfe list appears No Instance(s) Available and I want to see all the hotfixes installed, help me please, I'm running the command in Windows 7 x64

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Properly explain your situation and your problem. Also insert output/code snippets if any.

Comment: Are you running as administrator?

Comment: Yes, I'm running as administrator. I'm running the following code

C:\Windows\system32>wmic /node: RCSOFI017556L qfe list

 and after a few seconds only appears this

No Instance(s) available

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try Get-HotFix with PowerShell.

Comment: I tried with powershell and the command get- hotfix but no upgrade is not listed

PS C: \ Users \ soporte.drcs > get -hotfix

and after a few seconds only appears this

PS C: \ Users \ soporte.drcs >

Comment: Get-HotFix with PowerShell only returns a list of HotFix's that have already been installed. Please explain with some details how to use Get-HotFix in PowerShell to fix the "No Instance(s) available" problem. Which HotFix needs to be installed (or reinstalled) in order to fix this?